# systemd script for starting my app server as soon as it is down or system is rebooted

Tags: linux, systemd, ubuntu-16.04, upstart

I have a upstart configuration file as shown below which works fine in Ubuntu 14:

```
#/etc/init/data_server.conf
#sudo start data_server
#sudo stop data_server
#sudo status data_server

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

chdir /opt/hold/data_server
respawn

post-start script
    echo "data server started at `date +"%F %T"` on `hostname -f`" | mailx -r "abc@host.com" -s "data server Started" "pqr@host.com"
end script

post-stop script
  sleep 30
end script

limit core unlimited unlimited
limit nofile 100000 100000
setuid goldy
exec ./data_server --init_file=../config/tree.init --port=8080 --dir=/data/hold/ --max_sec=2400 --max_mb=100 --active=5
```

Now we are moving to Ubuntu 16 so we can't use `upstart` and looks like we need to use `systemd` here. What are the changes I need to do to write script in `systemd`?

I have to make sure whenever system is rebooted or app is killed it should start my `systemd` script automatically which in turn start my `data server`.

Comment: Please try writing the unit yourself, and ask for help with anything where you run into difficulty. This is not a service for doing your work for you. See the [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your upstart script will change a lot. You shouldn't need to manually specify so many directives, so it will also be a lot shorter.

Making a process always start on boot and restart when it crashes is a simply one line:

```
Restart=always
```

I don't know how many custom changes you need to keep, but at the very minimum, it looks like you'd need to keep the `chdir` and `exec` commands.

Here is an example of a basic systemd script for your app:

```
[Unit]
Description=My-service

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/opt/hold/data_server
ExecStart=/path/to/data_server --init_file=../config/tree.init --port=8080 --dir=/data/hold/ --max_sec=2400 --max_mb=100 --active=5
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I found this to be a handy resource when writing custom unit files: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html

Comment: got it make sense now.. I am gonna check that link.. Also by any chance do you know what I can do for these stuff `limit core unlimited unlimited`, `limit nofile 100000 100000` and `setuid goldy`.

Comment: I don't know much about upstart, so I couldn't advise all the translations. However, if you search that page that I linked, it does talk about setting the UID. It maybe also have info for those other custom directives.

Comment: @BoomShadow: AFAIK the `ExecStart` has to start with an absolute path to an executable.

Comment: @Thomas Ah yes, you're right. I forgot about that. Thanks. I updated my answer with generic example.